# How can I use redux persist for only one reducer not for navigation reducer in my react native application?

Tags: react-native, redux

I am using Redux persist to persist my store for reducers. My application has two reducers Navigation and User Reducer.I want to persist only user state but I have to persist both states according to this syntax of redux persist.

```
          import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist'
          const store = createStore(reducer, undefined, autoRehydrate())
          persistStore(store)
```

the reducer that I have passed in the create store is the object of combine reducers.

**Problem:**
The problem I am getting through this is when I exit my app, as the navigation state is also persist now, my app opens the same page from which I exited my app.

I am using navigation experimental with redux in my app and want to persist only user state.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[redux-persist v5](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Set the blacklist/whitelist in the [PersistConfig](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/api.md#type-persistconfig), and use it in [persistCombineReducers](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#usage) (the 1st param):

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  blacklist: ['navigation'],
  storage,
}

const reducer = persistCombineReducers(persistConfig , reducers)
```

[redux-persist v4](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/tree/v4.8.2)

[persistStore](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/tree/v4.8.2#persiststorestore-config-callback) can have an optional config object as the 2nd parameter. In the config object, you can define a black list of reducers to ignore, or a white list of reducers to include (and ignore the rest). Both accept an array of reducers' key names.

You can blacklist the `navigation` (or whatever yours is called) reducer:

```
persistStore(store, { blacklist: ['navigation'] })
```

Comment: is it possible to black/white list specific fields inside a specific reducer?  Say I want to whitelist my App reducer, but inside of that I only want to white list user email, for example?

Comment: actually I think to do what I want I should create another reducer specifically for persisted fields

Comment: The blacklist and whitelist accept reducer names. You can use the [transform filter](https://github.com/edy/redux-persist-transform-filter) to remove properties from a reducer state before it is stored.

Comment: You may also use import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist' to perform custom rehydrate yourself to exclude items that you don't want to merge during start up (rehydrate).