# How to use whitelist in redux-persist v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I try to use whitelist in redux-persist v5.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018091/how-can-i-use-redux-persist-for-only-one-reducer-not-for-navigation-reducer-in-m) on Stack Overflow, like below

```
persistStore(store, { whitelist: ['messages'] });
```

However, I got the error

> invalid option passed to persistStore: "whitelist". You may be incorrectly passing persistConfig into persistStore, whereas it should be passed into persistReducer.

Then I tried something like below after reading the redux-persist [readme file](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#transforms)

```
const transform = createTransform(null, null, {
  whitelist: [
    'messages'
  ]
});

const config = {
  key: 'state',
  storage: localForage,
  transforms: [transform]
};

const reducer = persistReducer(config, rootReducer);
```

But it does not work. It still saves everything through localForage.

So what is the correct way to use whitelist in redux-persist v5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using [redux-persist v5](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#usage), you should pass the [PersistConfig](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/api.md#type-persistconfig), as the 1st parameter of `persistCombineReducers`:

```
const config = {
  key: 'root',
  whitelist: ['messages']
}

const reducer = persistCombineReducers(config, reducers)
```

Note: they've made several changes in v5, read the docs carefully to create the enhanced store, and optionally using the [PersistGate](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/PersistGate.md).